# Iterate through two fields in a dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm passing a URL value to the API and writing the results into a CSV. I also wanted to read the id from the input file and add it in the CSV. Should I write an exclusive function to get this or are there other ways inside python for such needs?

Since I'm passing only URL to my code I'm able to add only that to my final output. How can I improve this solution?

My dataframe:

```
id, url, somethig
1, google.com,
2, yahoo.com,
3, rediffmail.com
4, null
5, null
```

My code:

```py
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     api='api.com/{row}' //passing the url (row) to api
     response= api.get(api,auth,params)
     jsondata=json.loads(response)
     response= jsondata['url']
     result={'urldetails': url_data } //collecting the data inside a diction to reconcile it into a csv
```

My current output:

```
urldetails
www.google.com
www.yahoo.in
rediffmail.co.us
```

I want the following as output:

```
id, urldetails
1,www.google.com
2,www.yahoo.in
3,rediffmail.co.us
```

Comment: Your url response is in python list format (url_data variable format)?

Comment: sorry. i mean there is a json loads . i didn't include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following,
Assuming, you have list in `url_data`

```
import pandas as pd

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    api='api.com/{row}' //passing the url (row) to api
    response= api.get(api,auth,params)
    jsondata=json.loads(response)
    jsondata= response['url']
    result={'id':row['id'],'urldetails': url_data }
```

`result` will be having the required output.

Comment: thanks for looking but will this logic mess up if have nulls or na in my input dataframe.

Comment: Can you share the sample of your input dataframe? Or sample JSON response output of API?

Comment: input df you can find in the desc.it goes by 'My df' in the desc....You can ignore the api output, i can take care of that. My only worry is how to add the id field in the output.

Comment: mann....was so simple!! how in the world i didn't that way. You beauty!!! thank you mate